# PHP URL Directory

Tags: php, url

If the URL is the following :

If:    `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/dnr/`
Then:  `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/dnr/`

If:    `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/dnr/?`
Then:  `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/dnr/`

If:    `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/dnr/index.php`
Then:  `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/dnr/`

If:    `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/dnr/page.php?var=2`
Then:  `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/dnr/`

If:    `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/dnr`
Then:  `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/`

How can I do this?

My attempt:

```
print "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at parse_url() function.

It returns anything you need.

Simply print_r() the result from parse_url to see what you get back.
You probably want something like:

```
$ARRurlParts = parse_url($orgurl);

$newURL = $ARRelem["scheme"].
"://".$ARRelem["host"].
((isset($ARRelem["port"]))?":".$ARRelem["port"]:"").
$ARRelem["path"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your "attempt" is that $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will contain everything the user passed, including index.php and question mark and possibly more.  In order to get what you are after, you need to parse the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

- If it ends with a slash `/`, leave it as it it
- Otherwise, find the last slash in the string and take the substring from the beginning up to and including this slash
- Finally append the result onto the `http://` (or `https://` with the domain name)

Answer (score 1):

Ended up going with this

```
$s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";
$protocol = substr(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), 0, strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/")) . $s;
$port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
$address = $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $port . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parseUrl = parse_url(trim($address));
$parent = (substr($parseUrl['path'], -1) == '/') ? $parseUrl['path'] : dirname($parseUrl['path']) . "/";
return $parseUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $parseUrl['host'] . $parseUrl['port'] . $parent;
```

Inspired in part by Erwin Moller's answer (Why I voted it) and snipplets across web.

Answer (score -1):

You can strip everything from the last backslash till the end of the string. I am pretty sure that `dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` won't do the job. You can also try using `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])`. The last shoud work if you don't have some fancy .htaccess rewrite rules.

Comment: I'm sure you meant "slash" and not "back-slash".

Comment: Yep, this is the "forward slash" or simply "slash"