# Trying to cut off the file portion of a URI/URL

Tags: php, string, url

I'm trying to cut the last portion of a URI as such:

```
public://path1/path2/path3/filename.extension
```

Ultimately I just want `public://path1/path2/path3/` or `public://path1/path2/path3`

I've tried using explode, but that seems to have some trouble with :// part of the URL. I'm trying to see if there's a way to do it with substr and strpos.

Any ideas?

Oh, I wasn't clear, I meant PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP URL Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626690/php-url-directory)

Answer (score 1):

My proposal:

```php
$url = 'http://public/protected/private/filename.php';
$url = str_replace(strrchr($url, '/'), '', $url);
echo $url; // Displays: http://public/protected/private
```

Docs:

- [strrchr function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)
- [str_replace function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

**This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)